# Hydrated electrons produced by radiation vs electrons from electrostatic charge: are they equally reactive?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, electrons, electrolysis, electricity

One of the species generated in water or aqueous solutions by the ionizing radiations are free electrons that quickly become "hydrated" or "aqueous electrons" (see for example [this](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-physchem-052516-050816) or [this](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.ns.15.120165.001013)), and it is said that this is a chemically reactive species (reducing agent).

But the body can get charged with static electricity apparently with no harmful effect (for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VYMpsErerg)). In case of getting negatively charged, does the extra electrons also forms hydrated electrons? Are they equally reactive? If not, why not?

Comment: Hydrated electrons are extremely reactive. In contrary to liquid ammonia, one need extra fast camera with thousands frames per second to catch their blue color during reaction of alkali metals with water. // Electrostatically charged body  does not have the electrons hydrated, but they joined organic tissues, forming charged ionic structures.

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate a little or point me in the good direction to look for some info about those charged ionic structures? If most part of the cells is water, one may think that the electrons from electrostatic charge can be in this water too. Maybe they join the mollecules of the cell membrane?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in electron reactivity between radiation-origin electrons and electrostatic electrons.

The difference is in the location of their landing zone and reactivity of their neighborhood. The former can land at any point within a bulk material in the reach of ionizating radiation. The latter land only on surface.

Electrons are too small with too high intensity of their electrostatic field to stay "naked" as they are. They bind to atoms, preferable to ones with high  electron affinity.

Electrons have  few major options:

1. Binding to some organic molecule, like  $\ce{R_1-A-R_2 + e- -> R_1-A^{-}-R_2}$ or $\ce{R_1-A^{+}-R_2 + e- -> R_1-A-R_2}$
2. Reducing some redox system like:  $\ce{\text{ox_form} + e- -> \text{red_form}}$
3. Reacting with active hydrogen, typically from $\ce{OH}$ group of water, alcohols or sugars, like $\ce{e-(aq) + H-OH -> H. + OH-(aq)}$, $\ce{e-(aq) + H3O+(aq) -> H. + H2O}$, $\ce{2 H -> H2}$